# Unable to connect to kafka broker of HDP Sandbox from Host machine

Tags: apache-kafka, hortonworks-sandbox

I am unable to connect to kafka broker (http://127.0.0.1:6667) of Hortonworks Sandbox 2.6 from my host machine. Every time I connect, it is saying the site is not reachable. What I am doing wrong.

FYI, I have enabled port forwarding for 6667 for my sandbox.

Comment: I might be way of the mark here, but check your Kafka configuration values for listeners and advertised.listeners, when you connect to a Kafka broker, the url you provide (localhost:6667) is only used initially, for subsequent requests the value from advertised.listener (if configured) or listener are used. If those for example point at localhost:9092 which is not reachable from outside the sandbox then it will not work. Just a guess though, if its not that, please provide a bit more information on configuration and how you are trying to connect.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked this: https://de.hortonworks.com/tutorial/sandbox-port-forwarding-guide/section/1/#add-ports-to-the-docker-script

Essentially you also need to enable port forwarding for the Docker Sandbox, just Host -> VM wont suffice, you need Host -> VM -> Docker container.

Helped in my case for Sandbox HDP 2.6+

Comment: I wont duplicate the contents found under the link - it's official hortonworks documentation which is stable for all that matters.

Comment: [Official policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/258777) is that your answer must be useful without the link.  I see you've edited to include a brief summary; thank you.  FYI a common practice when answering with documentation is to include the contents of the link directly in your answer with blockquote formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka is not an HTTP server; your browser will never be able to reach that address.

You will need to download Kafka CLI tools or SSH into the machine to connect to Kafka.